# What is the difference between afterInteractive and lazyOnload strategies?

Tags: next.js

In the new [`next/script`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) component we have the following strategies:

> `afterInteractive` (**default**): For scripts that can fetch and execute **after** the page is interactive, such as tag managers and analytics. These scripts are injected on the client-side and will run after hydration.

> `lazyOnload`: For scripts that can wait to load during idle time, such as chat support and social media widgets

Both definitions look alike, how are they different?

Answer (score 5):

Websites often need third parties for things like analytics, ads, customer support widgets, and consent management. However, these scripts tend to be heavy on loading performance and can drag down the user experience. Developers often struggle to decide where to place them in an application for optimal loading.

With next/script, you can define the strategy property and Next.js will optimize loading for the script:

beforeInteractive: For critical scripts that need to be fetched and executed before the page is interactive, such as bot detection and consent management. These scripts are injected into the initial HTML from the server and run before self-bundled JavaScript is executed.

afterInteractive (default): For scripts that can fetch and execute after the page is interactive, such as tag managers and analytics. These scripts are injected on the client-side and will run after hydration. This time is basically when browser has downloaded necessary files of the website so it can load the website and is interactive .

lazyOnload For scripts that can wait to load during idle time, such as chat support and social media widgets. Idle time means when the page is not loaded fully on the browser so when user opens the website it will download js and css files and all other necessary files then load the scripts .